# PhoneGap Desktop opens a nw.js window

Tags: cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I have followed the steps to install *PhoneGap* Desktop on my `x64` `Win7`. I have installed Node.Js and then continued according to http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/.

Once installation is complete and I run the program, I expect to see this window:

[image]

But instead I am receiving this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with `phonegap-app-desktop`

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/303
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/362